# svn2git cryptic error

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to import SVN repo into GIT.
svn2git terminates with this error message:

> command failed:
>   2>&1 git svn fetch

When I'm trying to run "git svn fetch" manually, it gives this error:

> r8641 = dbb23736330e97c356a5ecd0dd29634265b7956c
>   (refs/remotes/svn/trunk) Permission denied: Can't open
>   '/tmp/report.tmp': Permission denied at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 3187

(running script under admin rights).

Any advise?

UPD I've noticed, that before this error happens - some files are processed successfully (i.e. svn fetch executes for some time). The error happens in random time after command start, usually in a few seconds.

Comment: Do you have a directory called `/tmp` (`C:\tmp`) on your system, which you have write access to?

Comment: @knittl, created it - still having the same error.

Comment: Do you have anti-virus running?  Sometimes they affect file system operations. :-(

Comment: Tried disabling it - no help.

Comment: What are the lines just before the error message of git-svn?

Comment: "Running command: git svn fetch", then a list of processed files, and then error message.

Comment: You use a x64 system - I had luck using x86 instead... And maybe a git update will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running svnserve with -d -r can be a solution:

http://blog.dbtracer.org/2010/01/20/porting-subversion-git-with-error/

Comment: Still accessible through webarchive.org ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are accessing this file locally and using different formats for your original svn repo and the git instance that is migrating from svn to git (most likely your git is behind your svn repo version) - instead try running the migration through an svn server - try starting up an svn server with

`svnserve.exe -d -r /path/to/repo`

and then try your import again using:

`git.exe svn init -s "svn://localhost/repo_name"`

The problem is not your permissions, but a mismatch of versions

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/69):

> I had the same problem, happens when an error occurs (i missed some authors in the authors file) in the middle of the process. I solved it by removing the directory in where you executed svn2git, recreate it and execute it again. Still this isn't a solution and this issue needs to be fixed.

Comment: Didn't do the trick for me. I'm not sure this is the same problem. svn fetch _does_ work, but it terminates after a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I had this problem when there were users in the repository I was converting that didn't exist in the authors file.